# How to prove $\cos(x)=\cos(-x)$?

Tags: real-analysis, trigonometry

Couldn't I just argue with the definitions $\cos(z):=\frac{1}{2}(e^{iz}+e^{-iz})$?

So $\cos(z):=\frac{1}{2}(e^{iz}+e^{-iz})=\frac{1}{2}(e^{-iz}+e^{iz})=\cos(-z)$

???

Comment: Mh, a correct definition would be better...

Comment: There are some issues with the question: there are $x$ and $z$ in the equations and only one of the := signs is correct.

Comment: now the definition is correct.

Comment: If that is your definition then yes you can do that.  But if this is an earlier course and $\cos$ has a geometric interpretation you can use symmetric reflexivity of a circle.  How you prove it depends entirely on your definitions and context.

Comment: sorry, I am a little off today.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are told that the definition of cosine is $$\frac12\left(e^{ix} + e^{-ix} \right),$$

yes, you have proven it by using commutative property. Note that there is a slight inconsitency for confusing $z$ with $x$.

Comment: I would say it's rather $e^{ix}$ than $e^x$ (and the same concerning $e^{-x}$).

Comment: thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong with your argument, although some of the notation is wrong, as long as that identity has not been used in the proof that formula, which it has not. There are a plethora of other ways to prove this, though.